# Where is the "community wiki"?

Tags: support

Dumb question: Where is the community wiki?

I've seen mention of wiki pages for answer common things. I also saw mention, (in the review interface,) that too many edits on a question/answer can kick the question into community wiki mode. I see there's a "community wiki" checkbox below the area for entering an answer... but I don't want to just click and start banging around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More often than not, the Community Wiki feature was used to allow questions which otherwise would not be allowed on the site. That's why we largely deprecated the feature — [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

With the addition of the [suggested edits feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/), legitimate use cases are becoming diminishingly rare. Setting posts to 'community wiki' is still available on answers but has been disabled on question threads.