# How do we work out a concept together?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-scope

I just noticed this question: [Network-related regular expressions](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/446/network-related-regular-expressions). Actually, it's not a question, but it's compiling some useful snippets for work, done by the original poster, with an invitation to extend it.

Ho do we deal with such an approach?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest

- Post a proper question, which clearly describes the goal (or edit such an existing question).
- Post an answer, possibly structured with headings, which other people could extend.
- Possibly make this answer "Community Wiki" (see the FAQ), so there's a lower barrier for editing the answer and a clear signal of inviting the community to contribute.

There's no reputation for votes on CW post. However, they count for badges, so the starting poster or answerer has a good chance to get one or more badges, if the content is valuable.

Answer (score 3):

We don't work out concepts together on the main site. (We do work them out here in meta. :) We ask specific, technical questions and get ["hope for"?] good answers.

See also [Where is the community wiki](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/where-is-the-community-wiki). I don't think marking the [What are your network-related regular expressions?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/446/what-are-your-network-related-regular-expressions) question as a community wiki is a solution. That question should be closed as off topic.

Comment: Yes, such questions may collect a lot of "here's my version" answers and voting by comparing, but not a real fitting answer. Do you have a better title suggestion? Sometimes it may be good to work out a canonical solution together.

Comment: That particular regex discussion should be closed as off topic. If the OP had a particular question -- I looked and didn't see a specific question within the open discussion he proposed -- then sure, it could be reworked and kept as on-topic.

Comment: So, within Stack Exchange structure IS there place for discussions and general sharing of information?  In addition to just specific questions and their answers I'd love to have a place where I can learn what tools folks are using and see open-ended discussions but SE doesn't really seem to include that.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveNoonan i've no idea. I recommend posting your question as a new question here in Meta.